# Can you Change the Default Participant Search Profile?

Tags: civievent, search, custom-search, participants

I know you can change the default contact search profile but can you change the default participant search profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe configurable search profiles are only available for Advanced Search, and then only when results are displayed as Contacts. From the inline help for Advanced Search:

> Views For Display Contacts
>
> If you are displaying the search results as contacts, you can modify the columns displayed by creating a Profile containing a different set of contact fields and then selecting that Profile here. For example you may want to include columns for Gender and Date of Birth, while eliminating Country. [(Learn more...)](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles)

Documentation:

- [Customizing the user interface - Customizing search views](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/#customizing-search-views)
- [Profiles - Customising your user interface](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#customising-your-user-interface).